# Is it posible to a make generic return type from member

Tags: c#, generics

Is it possible to create a Method that requires a Generic Type, And then the return type is based on a member of the given Type

Something Like this

```
class ExampleClass
{
    public T.ReturnType Send<T>() where T : ClassWithType
    {
        ...
    }
}

abstract class ClassWithType
{
   internal abstract Type ReturnType { get; }
}
```

And if it's not possible what would be a good alternative.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to do here. A more *concrete* example may help. I.e. you ask for an alternative but there's not enough info here to understand the actual problem being solved.

Comment: I want to create a Method with Requires a Type. And returns an object based on the given type.

Comment: Also, bear in mind that generics are compiled to a single form - at the moment, `ClassWithType` could return *different* `Type`s every time that property is accessed so would be trying to vary the methods return type at *runtime*. That's definitely not going to play well.

Comment: No. I think the closest you can get is making Send generic on another parameter, but it's a bit hard to tell if that would cause other obstacles since we don't know how this is used or what's going on in Send.

Comment: The return type is not dynamically created. it's always the same for the given type

Comment: @CodeJoy - maybe that's your *intention* but there's no way to *enforce* that. As I said, for all we (and the compiler) knows, that property could be returning a *different* type every time it is called.

Comment: @CodeJoy what is the intention behind a generic method without arguments? What is the user case?

Comment: I want to send a packet with a socket. And the packages are encoded in the given object. But every packet has a different return type.

Comment: My point was that generic arguments are there to let you have one implementation instead of a whole bunch of methods that have the same logic and signature, but their parameter types are different. It is not useful to have a generic method without arguments of that generic type or its return type being that generic type, at least I don't see any sense in that.

Comment: The implementation you have can be replaced by `public T Send<T>() { }` without any loss of generality.

Comment: Why not just do `public class Packet<TResponse> { }; public TResponse Send<TResponse>(Packet<TResponse> packet) { }`? No need to specify return type, return type depends on packet class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it comments you said you want to send a packet via socket and each packet has different return type - you can encode return type in packet class itself:

```
public abstract class Packet<TResponse> {
    // other members here
    public abstract TResponse DecodeResponse(byte[] raw);
}

public class IntPacket : Packet<int> {
    public override int DecodeResponse(byte[] raw) {
        // decode
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Then your Send method becomes:

```
static TResponse Send<TResponse>(Packet<TResponse> packet) {
    // send, got response
    byte[] raw = GetResponse();
    return packet.DecodeResponse(raw);
}
```

And call becomes just:

```
int response = Send(new IntPacket());
```

Comment: I didn't know it was possible to do this
`int response = Send(new IntPacket());` instead of `int response = Send<int>(new IntPacket());`

Comment: That's possible in this case (for this particular Send method), because compiler sees that `IntPacket` is `Packet<int>` and so can infer the type. There are cases though when it's not possible for compiler to do that (or it is possible in theory but for various reasons compiler won't do that). In those cases you would have to supply types yourself.